# Synchronizing the threads.

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to synchronizing the two threads.

let there are two threads A & B, Now if A is on running condition then B should be stop until the A is running.

How can i do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use [the WaitHandle class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.aspx) to synchronize your threads.

See the example provided by MSDN (above link).